# Meaning of "impregnating" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, reading

> A functionalist approach to the role of dance in society is summarised in Radcliffe-Brown's view that the basic conditions for an orderly social existence depend on the transmission and maintenance of culturally desirable sentiments; and this leads us to turn from impregnating the young with such sentiments, to revitalising the sentiments of adults through dance. In this context, it is useful to consider a verbal-nonverbal scale of human interaction in relation to dancelike behaviour.

[image]

I assume it doesn't mean putting a baby in youth?

Comment: I would call this an unfortunate usage, one likely to be misunderstood (as in your case) or made jokes about.

Comment: "Indoctrinate" would be a *much* more appropriate word here, and I wonder if the author just made a poor word choice.

Comment: @MarkBeadles "Indoctrinate" has negative connotations. "Instill such sentiments in the young" would be better.

Comment: Besides the [edit] needed to add your research, we'd like you to put the text you're asking about in the question itself. Images can't be searched and don't work well with assistive devices. You should also properly credit the source.[⁺](/help/referencing "“How to reference material written by others” – EL&U Help")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To impregnate can mean to cause something to be absorbed by something else. When Radcliffe-Brown is talking about impregnating the young with sentiments, he is talking about causing young people to absorb ideas.

> impregnate verb [ T ] (ABSORB) ​ to cause something, usually a solid
>   substance, to absorb something, usually a liquid

[Impregnate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/impregnate)